# I am considering mulch for my orchard but i worry about fire?

Tags: fruit-trees, soil, mulch

I am considering some types of mulch for my orchard but I am really worried about fire. We have about three month(summer) without any rainfall and humidity is about 20-30%. For example if I use hay  or straw It would be like gasoline under trees that can ignite from a single cigarette. What kind of mulch should I use if I want to be safe from fire and also snakes. And how much should I be worried about these things?

Comment: It's all about location. where are you, have you had droughts? High temperatues for extended periods? More details please

Comment: Yes we have about three month(summer) without any rainfall and humidity is about 20-30%